# How do I get this board to print out like I want it to

Tags: java

Total noob to java and I have a homework where I need to make a custom chess game but I am even struggling with printing the gameboard which I am trying all the empty spaces to be with "X".
My current "code":

```java
public class Chess {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[][] board = new String[7][7];
        fillBoard(board);


    }
    public static void fillBoard(String[][] board){
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
                board[i][j] = "X";
                System.out.print(Arrays.deepToString(board));
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

It prints out:
[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8x31S.png)

When I want it to print out:
[Is this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLOEF.png)

Comment: Just do `System.out.print("X");` inside inner for loop. If you just want to print it, you don't need the array.

Comment: for now I want just to print it yes just so I can see the board is set up and ready to add things on to. But won't I need the array later when I try and add pawns?

Comment: A. Don’t print the entire array after each value you fill up

Comment: Replace `System.out.print(Arrays.deepToString(board));` with `System.out.print("X");`

Comment: @NotJhonWick45 Well I am not sure what you mean by adding pawns but yes you can fill the array with `X`'s

Comment: B. DeepToString will not give you the format you’re expecting (a new line between “rows”), to do that you can print the current value for each value you fill out, then print a column separator (space, comma, nothing). Between iterations of the outer loop you can print a new line (println)

Answer (score 1):

Just print the value of the position directly.

```
 public static void fillBoard(String[][] board){
            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
                    board[i][j] = "X";
                    System.out.print(board[i][j]);
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

After reading your comments, I realized that it's not just about printing the array that you are concerned about; rather, you are concerned about how you will be able to access it later. The solution to the problem of incorrect printing has already been provided in the comments i.e. replacing `System.out.print(Arrays.deepToString(board));` with `System.out.print("X");`. I am explaining here the other part (i.e. how to access it later) and also some additional information that will help you in designing your application.

1. When you pass and change an array in some method, the array will be changed for the calling method too (check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value) to learn more about it). It means that when `board[][]` will be changed in `fillBoard`, you will get the changed `board[][]` in `main`.
2. According to [Single-responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle), the module/method, `fillBoard` should do only one thing, which is filling up the board. It should not also do printing (additional thing). You should write a different method for printing.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[][] board = new String[7][7];
        fillBoard(board);
        displayBoard(board);
    }

    static void fillBoard(String[][] board) {
        for (String[] row : board) {
            Arrays.fill(row, "X");
        }
    }

    static void displayBoard(String[][] board) {
        for (String[] row : board) {
            for (String cell : row) {
                System.out.print(cell);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
XXXXXXX
XXXXXXX
XXXXXXX
XXXXXXX
XXXXXXX
XXXXXXX
XXXXXXX
```

**Additional note:**

A 2-D array is an array of 1-D arrays and therefore there are many ways in which you can write the code given above e.g.

```
static void fillBoard(String[][] board) {
    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        Arrays.fill(board[i], "X");
    }
}
```

**or using enhanced `for` loop:**

```
static void fillBoard(String[][] board) {
    for (String[] row : board) {
        Arrays.fill(row, "X");
    }
}
```

**or without using `Arrays.fill`:**

```
static void fillBoard(String[][] board) {
    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
            board[i][j] = "X";
        }
    }
}
```

**Similarly, the method, `displayBoard` can be written as:**

```
static void displayBoard(String[][] board) {
    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(board[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

**Note** that I have used `board.length` and `board[i].length` instead of `7` for the number of rows and `7` for the number of columns to make sure you don't have to change it every time you change the size of the array.